# Can't invoke snippets through their shortcuts

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Being New to Visual Studio 2013 Premium, I don't find any code snippets appearing in the IntelliSense help. I do notice a Code Snippets Manager.

Without using any Resharper tools, or Add Ins, can I get back the same shortcuts in Visual Basic and C# files?

Basically I'm saying that
`ctor`, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> isn't available, nor is `prop`, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

New Update: 
Works On CS files but not for VB files. Is there a setting I might have to tweak from the code snippet manager?

Comment: Did you copy them into the relevant snippets folder in your "Documents/Visual Studio 2013" directory?

Comment: No I haven't. I am moving between PCs, and this machine has a fresh install of VS2013. Can I install them any other way ?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure putting them in that folder is the standard way of "installing" a snippet. What method do you *expect* to work?

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't follow.

Comment: I think you calling them "my snippets" creates some confusion. Are you saying the built-in C# snippets like `prop` and `ctor` don't show up?

Comment: That's correct the built in ones. I didn't create a custom one.

Comment: Ah, thats a *very* different problem

Comment: Using the Code Snippet Manager I do see my language folders.
But mostly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring folders seem empty. Should I be finding a VSI file ?

Comment: Can you use `ctrl + k,s` to invoke snippets?

Comment: Essentially nothing..The key combination (Ctrl + k, S) is not a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the shortcut naming differences throwing you off?

In VB the built in snippet for a property is property (tab) (tab).  I don't believe there is a snippet for a constructor in VB since "Sub New" (enter) gets the job done.

You should be able to right click and select insert snippet to navigate the built in VB snippet options and see the shortcuts associated.

Comment: Wow! thanks. That cleared it out for me. I totally missed that.